# div how to make customize an item layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to play around with div to get the item layout that I need, but I can't achieve what I'm looking for

[image]

```
.skills-container
{
height:50px; /* something like 50px */
padding:5px;
}
.skill-pic
{
width:48px;
height:48px;
}
.skill-content
{
}
.skill-content p
{
}
.progress
{
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="skills-container">
    <div class="skill-pic">
        <img src="img/ps.png" alt="Klematis" width="48" height="48">
    </div>
    <div class="skill-content">
        <p>Photoshop</p>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-success">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question, please?

Comment: @deweyredman I want the layout you see in the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add float: left; to the .skill-pic css.

EDIT: Someone also pointed out this doesn't get exactly what you need.  You'll also need to add a border attribute to the css of the elements like so:

border: solid black 1px;  and replace the 1px with the size of the border you need... You'll have to play with it.

Try this as your CSS: it should work and you can tweak it as such... Working JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7VtHc/112/):

```
.skills-container
{
    display:inline-block;
    border: solid black 4px;
}

.skill-pic
{
    margin:2px;
    float:left;
    width:45px;
    height:45px;
}
img
{
    border: solid black 3px;
    height:45px;
}
.skill-content
{
    height:45px;
    width:200px;
    border: solid black 3px;
    float:left;
    margin:2px 2px 2px 5px;
}
.skill-content > div
{
    margin:2px;
    border: solid black 1px;
}
.progress
{
    margin:2px;
    border: solid black 1px;
}
```

Comment: Aside from the borders, it gets the positioning correct

Comment: @cale_b I agree with you, i tried float:left, doesn't achive the layout

Comment: In that case you can try floating both divs left, or just using display: inline-block for both items.

Comment: I tried float left for both of them before asking, and It didn't work

Comment: let me get a fiddle going for you, one second.  It's working for me.

Comment: Here you go: I'm still messing with it, but it's fairly close
http://jsfiddle.net/7VtHc/66/

Comment: I need `progress` to stretch to fill the remaining width of the container, `Container` should be streched to fill its outer container

Comment: I"m a little lost...the progress bar div fills the entire width of the  progress div...? just do a background-color: blue on the progress bar class and you can see that.